# Best way to order by children collection with Entity

Tags: range, entity, parent-child

I am seeking for the best solution for this simple problem.
Run in C#/Entity the following SQL:

```
select user.name, userstat.point from user, userstat where userstat.user_id = user.id order by userstat.point desc
```

There is a User table [Id, Name, ...] and Statistic table [Id, UserId, Point. ...], where it's connected to User by Statistic.UserId. It's a 1:1 relation, so there is (max) 1 Statistic record for each User record.

I want to have a list User+Point, ordered by Point desc, and select a range, let's say 1000-1100.

Currently I have this:

```
public List<PointItem> Get(int startPos, int count)
{
using (DB.Database db = new DB.Database())
{
   var dbList = db.Users.Where(user => .... ).ToList();

   List<PointItem> temp = new List<PointItem>(count);
   foreach (DB.User user in db.Users)
   {
       //should be always 1 stat for the user, but just to be sure check it...
       if (user.Stats != null && user.Stats.Count > 0)
          temp.Add(new PointItem { Name = user.Name, Point = user.Stats.First().Point });
   } <--- this foreach takes forever

   return temp.OrderByDescending(item => item.Point).Skip(startPos).Take(count).ToList();
}

}
```

It works fine, but when I have 10000 User (with 10000 UserStat) it runs for 100sec, which is only 1000x slower than I want it to be.

Is there more efficient solution than this?

If I run SQL, it takes 0 sec basically for 10K record.

**EDIT**

I made it faster, now 100sec -> 1 sec, but still I want it faster (if possible).

```
var userPoint = db.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserStats.Count > 0 && ....)  
    .Select(up => new
    {
        User = up,
        Point = up.UserStats.FirstOrDefault().Point
    })
    .OrderByDescending(up => up.Point)
    .ToList();

var region = userPoint.Skip(0).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, the following code is 0.05 sec. Just need to go from child to parent:

```
    using (DB.Database db = new DB.Database())
    {
        var userPoint = db.UserStats
            .Where(s => s.User.xxx .....)
            .Select(userpoint => new
            {
                User = userpoint.User.Name,
                Point = userpoint.Point
            })
            .OrderByDescending(userpoint => userpoint.Point)
            .ToList().Skip(startPos).Take(count);
    }
```